# no changes detected when running makemigrations

Tags: python, django

After dropping every single relation in my database, and deleting everything inside workoutcal/migrations, I tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations`. This is what happened:

```
(workout) Sahands-MBP:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

How is this possible? The database is empty. There is nothing inside the migrations folder. Are there other things I should delete?

Comment: what is inside the table `django_migrations`?

Comment: Nothing. It's been dropped.

Comment: `workout=# \dt`
`Did not find any relations.`

Comment: have you deleted the migrations folder in the apps?

Comment: No, not the folder. Only the contents.

Comment: I would try deleting the folder entirely, especially if you've deleted `__init__.py`.  Then try making migrations with the app name, eg `./manage.py makemigrations app_name`

Comment: Interesting. Putting the app name in did the trick. Thx